# Sentry on React Native: Building for iOS breaks with "property 'options' not found on object of type 'PrivateSentrySDKOnly'"

Tags: ios, react-native, sentry, react-native-sentry

I am using CircleCI to build for iOS  (and Android) and recently, the iOS build fails with these error messages:

```
Compiling RNSentry.m

❌  /Users/distiller/project/node_modules/@sentry/react-native/ios/RNSentry.m:107:79: property 'options' not found on object of type 'PrivateSentrySDKOnly'

    if (appIsActive && !sentHybridSdkDidBecomeActive && (PrivateSentrySDKOnly.options.enableAutoSessionTracking || PrivateSentrySDKOnly.options.enableOutOfMemoryTracking)) {
               ^



❌  /Users/distiller/project/node_modules/@sentry/react-native/ios/RNSentry.m:107:137: property 'options' not found on object of type 'PrivateSentrySDKOnly'

    if (appIsActive && !sentHybridSdkDidBecomeActive && (PrivateSentrySDKOnly.options.enableAutoSessionTracking || PrivateSentrySDKOnly.options.enableOutOfMemoryTracking)) {
                                                                              ^



❌  /Users/distiller/project/node_modules/@sentry/react-native/ios/RNSentry.m:155:39: property 'getSdkName' not found on object of type 'PrivateSentrySDKOnly'

        @"name": PrivateSentrySDKOnly.getSdkName,
                                                                                                                                        ^



❌  /Users/distiller/project/node_modules/@sentry/react-native/ios/RNSentry.m:195:34: property 'options' not found on object of type 'PrivateSentrySDKOnly'

        if (PrivateSentrySDKOnly.options.debug
```

It has once worked to build for iOS, and I *think* this has something to do with the version of Sentry; I think I tried to update the Sentry version to 4.9.0, only to find that 4.9.0 has some serious issues (I think). I am not smart enough to dechiffer exactly what the conclusions here are, but I think it relates:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa/issues/1665
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/issues/2530
(I was looking for another URL that related, but cant find now)

Android works to build with the configs and whatnot, but iOS fails. I am not sure what do to do resolve this, and I would like some input =)

the package.json has Sentry 4.8.0:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.4",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^6.3.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "4.8.0",
    "@turf/distance": "^6.0.1",
    "axios": "^1.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "eventing-bus": "^2.0.1",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.4",
```

Here is the rest of my config/setup:

```
PS C:\Github\alfaonlinev3> npx react-native doctor
Common
 ✓ Node.js
 ✓ yarn

Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

Errors:   1
Warnings: 0
```

Note: I have Android Studio installed, and it is working for Android native project. No idea why doctor complains or how to resolve it, other than downloading another copy of Android studio?

```
envinfo:
  Visual Studio code: 1.73.1


  System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19044
    CPU: (24) x64 AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12-Core Processor
    Memory: 5.01 GB / 31.95 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.15.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 8.5.5 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Managers:
    pip2: 19.2.3 - C:\Python27\Scripts\pip2.EXE
    pip3: 21.1.1 - C:\Python39\Scripts\pip3.EXE
  Utilities:
    Git: 2.34.1.
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 28, 29, 30, 31, 33
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.0, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0
    Windows SDK:
      AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense: Enabled
  IDEs:
    VSCode: 1.73.1 - C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.CMD
    Visual Studio: 17.3.32519.111 (Visual Studio Community 2022), 16.11.32106.194 (Visual Studio Community 2019)
  Languages:
    Java: 19.0.1
    Python: 3.9.5
  Databases:
    SQLite: 3.32.2 - C:\Users\wagge\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\sqlite3.EXE
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 107.0.5304.121
    Edge: Spartan (44.19041.1266.0), Chromium (107.0.1418.56)
    Internet Explorer: 11.0.19041.1566


 IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Visual Studio: 17.3.32519.111 (Visual Studio Community 2022), 16.11.32106.194 (Visual Studio Community 2019)
  Languages:
    Java: 19.0.1
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
    react-native: 0.67.4 => 0.67.4
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

*UPDATE*

I ran npm-update, it suggested updating sentry to 4.10.1. After that was done, I see this change in package.json:

[image]

also yarn.lock

[image]

but still, the builds fails with the same error.

*UPDATE 2*

I check podfile.* and I see stuff like:

```
 podfile.lock:

  - RNSentry (3.4.2):
    - React-Core
    - Sentry (= 7.11.0)
  - RNSnackbar (2.4.0):
    - React-Core
  - RNSVG (9.13.6):
    - React
  - Sentry (7.11.0):
    - Sentry/Core (= 7.11.0)
  - Sentry/Core (7.11.0)
```

The file `podfile` does not contain "sentry" at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is your problem:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/pull/2599/files

Try to upgrade react native sentry to 4.10.1

Comment: Any tips on how? I used the "Sentry wizard", and it did not upgrade to 4.10.1...

Comment: update "@sentry/react-native": "4.8.0", to 4.10.1 in your package.json and run yarn or npm i

Comment: I tried it, both package.json and yarn.lock says 4.10.1, but builds fails just the same unfortunetly; updated question with images. Hmm...

Comment: ahh you also need to update pods like pod install --project-directory=ios --repo-update

Comment: Hmm, that isnt done by... react or something? This react-dev is very fuzzy for me =) and yes... I dont have a mac, so pod command does not work (not recognized)

Comment: you need to check logs and find which version of sentry you use on CI

Comment: I will see if I can see something, but ... isnt that meant to be updated when I run npm update and such? I thougt that was part of the "thing" with react-native, "Learn once, write anywhere"?

Comment: "which version you use on CI"

But, version of sentry is defined in package.json and gradle files and what not. There are no specific settings in CI (CircleCI) for any such packages?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250089/discussion-between-kirill-novikov-and-ted).

Answer (score 0):

From your `podfile.lock` it looks like you have an old version of the `RNSentry` pod installed.

```
 - RNSentry (3.4.2):
```

Try to run the following:

```
cd ios
pod update RNSentry
```

The `RNSentry` must be the same version as `@sentry/react-native`. So in your case it should've been `4.10.1`.